# Relocating a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to relocate a div - the expandable panel with the header 'Why Bother', so it appears where you see it now in the display (at the bottom). But in the HTML, I want it to appear at the top of the 8 panels.

(These panels are located all down the RH side of the content area. And I am doing this to retain the current sites SEO, which is where the guy who I am building this for makes 99% of his money).

http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/index.htm

I have tried using bottom:0; but this will not work with the expandable panels. Is there a way to do this using CSS or JS?

Comment: Do you want to display the 'Why bother' div at the top??

Comment: You will need to move it to the top in the HTML, and use javascript to reposition it. Won't be possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you you want it to appear at the top for SEO reasons, then you are going to have to move it to the top in your HTML code. Moving it after the DOM loads (with either JS or CSS) will have no effect on it's SEO, as the SEO spiders will read the DOM the way it appears in the original HTML.

Once you have moved it to the top, you can then move it to the bottom using javascript, so that it appears to be at the bottom.

Assuming it is the first div element in `<div class="contentLeft"` with the class `dropdownPanel` , You could use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.dropdownPanel:first').appendTo('#content div.contentLeft');
});
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsbin.com/ezizix/1/edit

I noticed on your site you have the `$` shortcut for jQuery disabled, so be sure to replace it with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('div.dropdownPanel:first').appendTo('#content div.contentLeft');
```

Comment: Awesome but still have the same issue with that last drop down panel. I've uploaded the changes as you have on the above link. It's all perfect other than the Why Bother drop down doesn't function as it should. How can I get the panel to drop down, instead of up? Thanks!

Comment: Did you reply to the wrong answer? I'm looking at your site now and you seem to have the element absolutely positioned using CSS, which explains why it isn't working.

Comment: OK, looking at your site, it appears you've implemented both my answer and Circadian's answer, together. Which means your moving it with both jQuery and CSS at the same time. As such it isn't working. If you use CSS your going to run into problems with the menu expanding upwards. Disable the CSS. Also, make sure you use the code that starts `jQuery('div` as your site is not set up to accept the use of `$` to call jQuery.

Comment: Hi Jeemusu - the code I used only came from your link - http://jsbin.com/ezizix/1/edit, I didn't use a mix, or any one elses code or reply. So, I should not use the CSS that you use in your link, and only use the jQuery?

Comment: Okay, I've removed the CSS, and added the correct jQuery from your reply. Here is what is happening - http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/. Have I missed something out?

Comment: It probably means you need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){});` updated my answer with some new code :)

Comment: So, add this: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.dropdownPanel:first').appendTo('#content div.contentLeft');
});   ...instead of this...   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('div.dropdownPanel:first').appendTo('#content div.contentLeft');
  </script>  ? If so, it's still the same?

Comment: I tried that, must have done something wrong but I did find this way - http://jsfiddle.net/3xhEW/3/ what do you think?

Comment: I can't actually take the credit but yeah it's pretty cool :) thanks so much for your help though really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with absolute positioning. I don't know if the dropdowns will work after this, but it is worth a try.

Add this to the existing `contentLeft` css rules

```
.contentLeft {
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Add this to the "special" div

```
.specialdropdownPanel {
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This will move it, but as far as I can tell the expandable behavior won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery before to do this [Example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/XZGpf/)

```
$(".contentLeft .dropdownPanel").eq(0).before($(".contentLeft .dropdownPanel").eq(7));​​​​
```